# Not enough plotting, graph is cut and asymptotes are not displayed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So, I just practicing some of suggested tikz code that I should use based on my previous questions. However, I have another problem where this code does not yield a perfect graph (I mean a full fit graph to grid). Below is my MWE although it may seems that I used the GeoGebra, but it is not though.

And, also I give how the code displays the graph and what I want it should look like.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = center,
xlabel = $x$,
ylabel = $y$,
xmax = 10,
xmin = -6,
ymax = 10,
ymin = -6,
xtick = {-4,-2,...,10},
ytick = {-4,-2,...,10},
domain = -8:6
]
\addplot[
  restrict y to domain = -8:10,
  samples = 200,
] {(x^2)/(x - 2)}; % <<<<< This is the function. Forgot to edit it
\addplot[dashed] {x + 2};
\addplot[dashed] (2, x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is my graph based on the code above, and I want to fix this graph

[image: The Graph]

And, this is precisely what I want it should be

[image: Graph I want it looks like this]

See that the second picture has a full line asymptote fit to the grid.

With or without grid is not a mandatory.

Solving this case in general means a lot to me, too.

Anyway, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is f(x) = (x^2 + 0.5*x + 1.5) / (x+3), which results in:

[image]

generated by the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-15, xmax=5, ymin=-15, ymax=5, axis lines= center, grid=both,
    restrict y to domain=-15:5]
    
    % f(x) 
    \addplot [domain=-15:5, samples=100] ({x},{(x^2+0.5*x+1.5)/(x+3)});
    
    % Asymptote at    x = -3
    \addplot [dashed, domain=-15:5] ({-3},{x});
    
    % Asymptote at    y = x - 5/2
    \addplot [dashed, domain=-15:5] ({x},{x-5/2});
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, so I should put the domain for the asymptote, is that right? So that the asymptote line will fit to the graph border?

Comment: You can set the domain locally (inside the `\addplot` options) or globally (inside `axis` options). You can see what happens if you put `domain=-10:5` in the second asymptote @WiloryLu

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks a lot!